# Download images to hidden folder

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, file-management, hidden

I have created a **hidden** folder using `.FolderName` technique in File Manager. How do I make all my downloads from a particular APP in this hidden folder (If at all this is a possibility) ?

- Android 4.4.2
- Micromax A315 (If this matters)

Comment: This  may be considered  a too broad question without involving a specific app. So, which app is it? Link it.

Comment: WhatsApp, Gmail and Outlook attachments

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will require some symlinking for those apps, but then the files are not hidden anymore. Remember that anyone who know how to access the settings menu, can simply view even hidden folders. To hide files I suggest you use a dedicated encrypted container (like TrueCrypt but for Android).

Comment: I heard this symlinking thing for the first time... Can you guide me through it? I am just a knowledge-seeker... This ain't a task for me. Just for fun